# How to Detect commas within a string and print the number of commas as well as where the commas occured within the string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, indexing, char

I've tried using a for loop to detect the commas within the given input of "Gil,Noa,Guy,Ari" and then list the location of the commas within the string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindCommas {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String delimitedData;
      int i;
        int freqOccurred = 0;
   
      delimitedData = scnr.nextLine();
      
      for (i = 0; i < delimitedData.length(); ++i) {
         if (Character.isLetter(delimitedData.charAt(i))) {
         System.out.println("Comma found at index " + i);
         }
      }
      
      for(String subString: delimitedData.split(",")){
         freqOccurred = freqOccurred + 1;
      }
      freqOccurred = freqOccurred - 1;

    System.out.println("Comma occurs " + freqOccurred + " times");
    }
}
```

The output it produces currently is:

Comma found at index 0

Comma found at index 1

Comma found at index 2

Comma found at index 4

Comma found at index 5

Comma found at index 6

Comma found at index 8

Comma found at index 9

Comma found at index 10

Comma found at index 12

Comma found at index 13

Comma found at index 14

Comma occurs 3 times

The problem is that it skips the index location of where the commas are and I cannot figure out how to flip it to only produce the index of the commas rather than just the index of the letters.

Expected output:

Comma found at index 3

Comma found at index 7

Comma found at index 11

Comma occurs 3 times

*note: code must not contain arrays*

(sorry for the poor formatting of the post)

Comment: Do you want to print that message for every character which isn't a letter, e.g. a digit? What problem are you having in flipping the condition?

Comment: i want to print a message for every character that is a comma.

Comment: Why don't you put a condition in your if statement which is `true` when the character at the current index is a comma?

Comment: how would that be done?

Comment: Read through some Java tutorials. Look at comparing the values of primitive types.

Comment: is there a condition that detects punctuation that is kinda like Character.isLetter?

Comment: nvm figured it out

Comment: Post the answer as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: @aled How would I do that?

Comment: Edit the question to remove the answer and post it below (section Your answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for those who want it:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String delimitedData;
      int i;
        int freqOccurred = 0;
   
      delimitedData = scnr.nextLine();
      
      for (i = 0; i < delimitedData.length(); ++i) {
         if (delimitedData.charAt(i) == ',') {
            System.out.println("Comma found at index " + i);
         }
      }
      
      for(String subString: delimitedData.split(",")){
         freqOccurred = freqOccurred + 1;
      }
      freqOccurred = freqOccurred - 1;

    System.out.println("Comma occurs " + freqOccurred + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to loop over an array to count its elements. `freqOccurred = delimitedData.split(",").length;` will do the job. Alternatively, count the commas in the first loop, where you already detect commas, instead of doing the same work twice.